# Android Studio compose preview not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-4.0

I can't preview any composables with Android Studio Arctic Fox Beta 4. Even the default one that is generated with an empty compose project. Running the default app on a hardware device doesn't work either
Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle.copy-H99Ercs$default(androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle, long, long, androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight, androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle, androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontSynthesis, androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily, java.lang.String, long, androidx.compose.ui.text.style.BaselineShift, androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextGeometricTransform, androidx.compose.ui.text.intl.LocaleList, long, androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDecoration, androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shadow, androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign, androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextDirection, long, androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextIndent, int, java.lang.Object)'
    at androidx.compose.material.TypographyKt.withDefaultFontFamily(Typography.kt:284)
    at androidx.compose.material.TypographyKt.access$withDefaultFontFamily(Typography.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.material.Typography.<init>(Typography.kt:186)
    at androidx.compose.material.Typography.<init>(Typography.kt:118)
    at com.example.widgettest.ui.theme.TypeKt.<clinit>(Type.kt:10)
    at com.example.widgettest.ui.theme.ThemeKt.WidgetTestTheme(Theme.kt:40)
    at com.example.widgettest.MainActivityKt.DefaultPreview(MainActivity.kt:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableMethod(PreviewUtils.kt:141)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewUtilsKt.invokeComposableViaReflection(PreviewUtils.kt:180)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:545)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:543)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:582)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:538)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:487)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:486)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:486)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:112)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:538)
    at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:535)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3324)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2575)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:523)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2564)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2515)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:724)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:811)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get preview in composable functions that depend on a view model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089816/how-to-get-preview-in-composable-functions-that-depend-on-a-view-model)

Answer (score 4):

Faced a similar problem. Solved by invalidating caches and restarting studio (from the File Menu), then rebuilding project.

Comment: This worked for me on AS BumbleBee 2021.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I can run it with a manually filled-in configuration. I made a new run configuration and set the path.  Maybe it is a bug.

[image: new configuration]

Tool:Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 7

Answer (score 0):

1. Be sure you have latest Android Studio version
2. Within project/build.gradle be sure you have

> ```
> dependencies {
>   classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20' 
> }
> ```

3. Within app/build.gradle be sure you have

> ```
> android {      
>   composeOptions {         
>       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion'1.1.1'  
>   }
>   
>   buildFeatures {          
>       compose true
>   }
> }
>
>
> dependencies {
>   implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.1.1")
>   // Tooling support (Previews, etc.)
>   debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.1.1"
>   implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.1.1"
>   // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
>   implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.1.1")
>   // Material Design
>   implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1")
>   // Material design icons
>   implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.1.1")
>   implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.1.1")
>   // Integration with observables
>   implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.1.1")
>   implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.1.1")
> }
> ```

4. File -> Invalidate Ccaches and restart
5. Run project once

Very important:
check for correct @Preview import - should be:

> import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

Example:

> ```
> @Composable
> fun SimpleComposable() {
>     Text("Hello World")
> }
>
> @Preview
> @Composable
> fun ComposablePreview() {
>     SimpleComposable()
> }
> ```

@Preview function should be without params.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227767363

Google is currently working on a fix but there is already a workaround: add these dependencies to every module where you use the Compose preview:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview:1.2.0-alpha01"
debugImplementation "androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0"
```